# Selecting only one radio button in the same row and column

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have a table of radio buttons. In clicking one, the whole column becomes selected. I am trying to get it so that only one radio button can be selected in the same row and the same column.

There's a similar post on this topic with a working answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26887972/2056066

However, being new to both Angularjs and Angular Material, I'm struggling to translate the code appropriately... Can anyone help? Thanks!

Edit: Code supplied as requested.

```
<md-radio-group ng-model="data.group1">
  <md-radio-button value="Apple" class="md-primary">Apple</md-radio-button>
  <md-radio-button value="Banana"> Banana </md-radio-button>
  <md-radio-button value="Mango">Mango</md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
```

Comment: The code you've posted works just fine - http://codepen.io/yccteam/pen/mPaBaJ. Could you post a live code that shows the error?

Comment: @yccteam It's a hurried example, but look here: http://codepen.io/JesterJeffrey/pen/VaqMRZ . While adding another data group may fix this issue, having another data group for every row of my table seems impractical...

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `ng-change` to monitor on which column user just clicked. `row` can be checked directly as I shown below. Here is the solution you were looking for.

```
 <md-content layout="column" flex style="background-color:orange">
<div layout="row" layout-margin>
  <md-radio-group layout="row" flex ng-model="selectedItem.row1.value"  ng-change=check(1,selectedItem.row1)>
    <md-radio-button ng-repeat="fruit in firstRow" ng-value="$index" class="md-primary" flex="20">{{fruit.name}}</md-radio-button>
  </md-radio-group>
</div>
<div layout="row" layout-margin>
  <md-radio-group layout="row" flex ng-model="selectedItem.row2.value" ng-change=check(2,selectedItem.row2)>
    <md-radio-button ng-repeat="fruit in firstRow" ng-value="$index" class="md-primary" flex="20">{{fruit.name}}</md-radio-button>
  </md-radio-group>
</div>
</md-content>
```

Controller

```
 $scope.selectedItem = {};

$scope.firstRow = {
  0: {
    name: "Apple 1",
    value: "apple1"
  },
  1: {
    name: "Banana 1",
    value: "banana1"
  },
  2: {
    name: "Mango 1",
    value: "mango1"
  },
   3: {
    name: "Grapes 1",
    value: "grapes1"
  },
   4: {
    name: "Strawberry 1",
    value: "strawberry1"
  },

};

$scope.check = function(row, data){

data.row = row;
data.name = $scope.selectedItem[data.value];

angular.forEach($scope.selectedItem, function(value,key){

  if(value.value === data.value && value.row != row){
    console.log(key)
    value.value = undefined;
    value.row = undefined;
  }
})
```

};

Here is the working Solution http://codepen.io/next1/pen/NNemvJ

Answer (score 1):

After seeing your live code, the answer is quite simple and it is related to how the radio buttons work.
You have setup a radio group with radio pairs with the same value.  Hence, when the `ngModel` was with the value `banana`, all radio buttons with the `value="banana"` were selected - as expected.
If you desire only one item to be selected at a time, you should set unique values in the same radio group:
http://codepen.io/yccteam/pen/grZGJM

```
<md-radio-group ng-model="data.group1">
<div layout="row" >
      <md-radio-button value="Apple" class="md-primary">Apple</md-radio-button>
      <md-radio-button value="Banana"> Banana </md-radio-button>
      <md-radio-button value="Mango">Mango</md-radio-button>
  </div>
   <div layout="row" >
      <md-radio-button value="Orange">Orange</md-radio-button>
      <md-radio-button value="Strawberry"> Strawberry </md-radio-button>
      <md-radio-button value="Rassberry">Rassberry</md-radio-button>
</div>
    </md-radio-group>
```

Comment: So there's no way to do this without changing the values? If so, is there anyway to change the values programmatically? The issue is that the rows of my table are generated based on my dataset and I have no way of setting the values beforehand...

Comment: ...and it seems changing values still doesn't allow for multiple selections in the same column; only one can be selected.

Comment: So that is what you want? Radio buttons are not intended for multiple selection.  Use checkboxes. Otherwise add an ngmodel for each radio button and drop the radio group. Sorry for not sharing an example. On mobile

Comment: No problem. I'm having trouble finding the words to explain my issue and I appreciate the help all things considered. I think you've got me on the right track; looking into using $index to define the appropriate groups and values. Thanks again!